# Async node.js :nested array with callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have an array like this

```
var products = [
            {'id':1 ,items:['a','b']},
            {'id':2,items:['c','d']}
           ]
```

what i want is loop through this array and do database insert for `items` array

eg without async

```
products.forEach((pdct) =>{

    pdct.items.forEach((item) => {
           calltoDb(item,function(result){
               console.log(item+'item inserted');
             })       
       });

});
```

I want the same to achive with `async` and get result after all items inserted

which one i need to use `each`  or `eachSeries` method i am confusing with it

Comment: you need to run `calltodb` parellel or one by one?

Comment: @zabusa calltodb one by one not parallel

Comment: you can achieve this in a clean way with `await Promise.all` without using caolan async module.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `each` and `eachSeries` is that the `eachSeries` runs a single async operation at a time. So for `each` there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will complete in order.

So if you don't need an order like in iteratee better to use `each`, otherwise use `eachSeries`

Examples:

```
import each from 'async/each'
let products = [
   {'id':1 ,items:['a','b']}
   , {'id':2, items:['c','d']}
   , {'id':3, items:['e','f']}
]
each(products, (product, callback) => {
   console.log(product)
   return callback()
})
```

It can return

```
{'id':3, items:['e','f']}
{'id':1 ,items:['a','b']}
{'id':2, items:['c','d']}
```

**eachSeries:**

```
import eachSeries from 'async/eachSeries'
let products = [
   {'id':1 ,items:['a','b']}
   , {'id':2, items:['c','d']}
   , {'id':3, items:['e','f']}
]
eachSeries(products, (product, callback) => {
   console.log(product)
   return callback()
})
```

It will return

```
{'id':1 ,items:['a','b']}
{'id':2, items:['c','d']}
{'id':3, items:['e','f']}
```

Comment: can you give an example with current scenario

Comment: @iambatman I updated my examples too. But it will be work with the same way like i shown before. eachSeries will loop array in that order what u provide in array. each do not guarantee to have same order like in array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use external libraries to performance a synchronous for loop in JavaScript, you just have to use the `async/await` syntax to do that

Take a look at this code that insert one by one your records waiting for each one to finish until jump to the next one.

```
async function insert() {
    var all_results = []
    for (var pdct of products) {
        for (var item of pdct.items) {
            var result = await new Promise(next => {
                calltoDb(item, res => next(res))
            })
            all_results.push(result)
        }
    }
    return all_results
}

insert().then(results => {
    console.log('Here u have all results', results)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you promisify that callback, you can do this pretty simply with `Promise.all`, which wraps an array of Promises and resolves once each Promise in the array resolves.

```
Promise.all(products.map(product => {
    return Promise.all(product.items.map(item => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            calltoDb(item, resolve)
        })
    }))
})).then(results => {
    console.log(results)  // item results are in a nested array:
                          //     [['a','b'],
                          //      ['c', 'd']]
})
```

If you are using Node 8 you could also get rid of the `.then` and use the `await` keyword instead:

```
const results = await Promise.all(products.map(product => {
    return Promise.all(product.items.map(item => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            calltoDb(item, resolve)
        })
    }))
}))
```